# Не обновляется CSS в Visual Studio 2015 при отладке

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

Отлаживаю MVC приложение, вношу изменения в CSS в интерфейсе в VS, запускаю отладку. И CSS остается старой версии до изменений. Все проверил, ссылки на CSS подтягиваются, кэш браузера почистил. И ничего, остановился как вкопанный. Почему?
Недавно случайно что-то потыкал в системе контроля версий, но потом всё отключил, может чего не так сделал.

Откуда такая проблема и как бороться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такой вариант решит проблему.

```
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css?v=@DateTime.Now.Millisecond" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Еще может быть так, если в проекте 2 файла:

```
~/Content/bootstrap.css
~/Content/bootstrap.min.css
```

Вы вносите изменения в `bootstrap.css` и при этом запускаете проект в режиме `Release`, то подгружаться всегда будет `bootstrap.min.css`.

Comment: Да, это решает проблему. Я тоже предположил, что CSS был кэширован и не перегружался, но отбросил эту версию, когда очистка кэша браузера не помогла. Почему не помогло?

Comment: Смутно помню, что есть какой-то вспомогательный метод, который делает по сути тоже самое - выводит ссылку на CSS в уникальном виде, но только если CSS менялся. Не напомните метод раз уж речь зашла? :)